# How do I implement Search in my List in LWUIT?

Tags: search, java-me, lwuit

On Shai's [blog](http://codenameone.blogspot.com/2009/09/lost-again-searchable-list-with-text.html) entry about Searchable list, I noticed that he commented that since he optimized LWUIT some things are broken.

I want to implement search on my list in LWUIT, please how do I implement? Some basic examples would also be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @casperOne if it was not a real question then why did Shai answer it? I wanted to implement search in my LWUIT list and I am asking for help - what is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, retorical or unreasonable about that?

Comment: Failed to show fundamental research; if you can't answer the question "what did you *do*", then it's NARQ.

Comment: @casperOne You should not jump to conclusions so easily. You do not appear to be an expert (or even a developer) in J2ME, or using LWUIT for that matter. IF you don't know something about a subject matter do not judge. That being said, I referred to Shai's blog post because I implemented his code therein and got errors. Made no sense repasting it here when I can just link to it. LWUIT code has evolved rapidly and the post was old (2009) and I wanted fresh examples. The RIGHT PERSON(s) already responded, so please stay out of LWUIT stratosphere and my issues. Thank you for your POLITENESS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is explicitly invoke `form.registerAnimated()` which was missing in my original demo code.